# Can icingaweb2 authenticate users using LDAP and database?

Tags: authentication, icinga2

I chose to use LDAP (Active Directory) as the authentication method to my new Icinga2 server (and it's working) but I don't want to rely on AD for the Icinga administrative accounts. Can I authenticate a few admin users locally (using MySQL) while allowing the non-administrative users access via AD? Is this commonly done or not recommended for any reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is supported. The folks in #icinga in freenode confirmed this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is supported. The folks in #icinga on freenode confirmed this and I actually got it to work.